# Error: json.load in python

Tags: python, json

why is this **true**:

```
  import json
  json.loads('{"A":2}')
```

but this is **wrong**:

```
  json.loads('{"A":2,}')
```

**OR**

```
  json.loads("['A':2]")
```

Comment: Because `{"A":2,}` (trailing comma) and `['A':2}` (`[]`,`{}` mismatch, key not in double quotes) are not valid JSON. See http://json.org/ and http://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 3):

JSON is a subset of JavaScript. This means things that are valid JavaScript are not necessarily valid JSON.

- `{"A":2,}` is valid JS (except in old IE versions), but not valid JSON
- `['A':2}` is not even valid JS since the braces do not match. If they matched, it would still be invalid JSON as JSON always uses `"` and never `'` to quote strings.

See http://json.org/ for the JSON specs.

Comment: oops , i mean `json.loads("['A':2]")`

Comment: @mehRad: Still wrong, because of (a) key is not in double quotes and (b) the `:` is invalid there. Either define an object: `{k:v, k:v, ...}` or an array `[v, v, ...]`. That's how JSON is defined, you just have to remember it. Therefore: http://json.org/

Answer (score 1):

Because the last two options are not a valid [json](http://json.org/)

- There should be no comma after last element
- a `[` should match a `]` (array) and  a `{` should match a `}` (object)